# Why getting NAN when i try to add index in end of the field?

Tags: javascript

good morning everyone

why I'm getting a NAN error when I try to add index value to the field.it supposes to return myForm.user0 and myForm.user1 inside the loop right? kindly please advise here

```js
var users=['a','b'];
var myForm ={
        
        $name:"testform",
        user0: {
            $dirty: false,
            $invalid: true,
            $name: "user0"
        },
        user1: {
            $dirty: false,
            $invalid: true,
            $name: "user1"
        }
        };
        
        
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                var s = myForm.user+i;
                console.log(s);

            }
```

the expected output is in the console log: it should return myForm.user0 and myForm.user1 in console

```
{$dirty: false,$invalid: true,$name: "user0"}
{$dirty: false, $invalid: true, $name: "user1"}
```

Comment: `myForm.user` is `undefined`, and `undefined + 1` is `NaN`. You need `myForm["user" + i]` However you should use an array instead, not consecutively numbered keys.

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, it's a value.

Comment: Great, but still: consider using `users: [{ ... }, { ... }]` instead.

Comment: ok I will consider your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

`myForm.user+1` is not accessing a member of the object. try using the following syntax: `myForm['user' + i]`